# How to P/Invoke a function with an unknown struct in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c

I know this sounds really strange, but I don't know how to even ask this properly. I've been trying to P/Invoke into NVidia's NVML library with limited success: I've managed to call a few of the APIs exported by that library

Now I am trying to call `nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex_v2` but I've been stuck for a long while on this one. It takes in a `nvmlDevice_t` pointer, but I've found nothing on what `nvmlDevice_t` actually is beyond this [header definition](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gpu-monitoring-tools/blob/master/bindings/go/nvml/nvml.h#L132):

```
typedef struct nvmlDevice_st* nvmlDevice_t;
```

The problem is that the header file does not make any other reference to `nvmlDevice_st` so I  don't know how much heap space to allocate for it, if any. I've found this [official C++ example](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/nvml_enterprise_gpu_check/blob/main/main.cpp#L112) that calls that same function like this:

```
nvmlDevice_t device;
CheckNVMLErrors(nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(device_index, &device));
```

My main problem is that I'm not familiar enough with C/C++ to understand the implicit mechanics/memory allocation done by the `device` declaration, and the `nvml.h` header does not  define what `nvmlDevice_st` actually is.

I tried calling it with a `ref int` parameter (with an initial `0` value) and apparently it does work but I want to understand why, if possible. For reference, the value of that `ref int` parameter after the call was `1460391512`, in case something can be gleamed off that.

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084272/passing-a-struct-containing-an-int-array-of-unknown-size-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-b

Comment: If you look at the source, that is just an internal pointer used by the SDK. The value it points to has no meaning to you. You use it to identify a device you are working with. Think `Handle` or `HWND` in windows. You call something like `FindWindow()`, it returns what seems to be a random value back to you. You don't care what that value holds, you just use that value to identify that window when you call `GetWindowText()` or any other windowing methods.

Comment: It is IntPtr, not int.  Hiding the implementation behind a *handle* is a very old mechanism to encourage language independence and avoid api abuse.  Your OS uses them heavily.  Google "handle based api" to learn more, the answers in [this SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294761/why-use-an-opaque-handle-that-requires-casting-in-a-public-api-rather-than-a-t) are not great, but may help to get the lay of the land.

Comment: I tried to call it as `ref IntPtr` with a variable initialized to `IntPtr.Zero` assuming it was a handle but I got back an Invalid Parameter error :( @HansPassant @Andy

Comment: try `out IntPtr`

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! Add an answer so I can properly flag it please @Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source, that is just an internal pointer used by the SDK. The value it points to has no meaning to you. You use it to identify a device you are working with.

Think `Handle` or `HWND` in Windows. You call something like `FindWindow()`, it returns what seems to be a random value back to you. You don't care what that value holds, you just use that value to identify that window when you call `GetWindowText()` or any other windowing methods.

So, you are on the right track with using `ref int`, but what you want is a pointer. So you should use `out IntPtr` to get the value.

Comment: To expand a bit on your answer, this is the final DllImport declaration:
`[DllImport("nvidia-ml.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex_v2")]
        public static extern ReturnCodes GetDeviceHandleByIndex(int index, out IntPtr handle);`

Comment: @Machinarius -- excellent, glad it worked out :) I love doing that kind of stuff. Reverse engineering is a ton of fun.